# Does kafka have any default web UI

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a couple questions in Kafka.

1) Does Kafka have a default web UI?

2) How can we gracefully shutdown a standalone kafka server, kafka console-
 consumer/console-producer.

Any solutions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) No Kafka does not have a default UI.

There are however a number of third party tools that can graphically display Kafka resources. Just Google for `kafka ui` and pick the tool that displays what you want and you like the most.

2) To gracefully shutdown a Kafka broker, just send a `SIGTERM` to the Kafka process and it will properly shutdown. This can be done via the `./bin/kafka-server-stop.sh` tool.

If it's part of a cluster, new leaders will be elected on other brokers, otherwise it will simply cleanly close all its resources. Note that depending on the number of partitions, this can take a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try *Landoop* Kafka UI: https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev
They provide a nice Web-UI for Kafka topics, Avro schemata, Kafka Connect and much more.

Comment: Great solution. Too bad it doesn't work for M1 Macs right now.